# Generic converter can't infer type

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I'm trying to write this converter to work with all types. So I'm using generics. But receive the following compile-time error.

```
error CS0411: The type arguments for method 'SomeConverter.ConvertToList<T>(ArrayLike)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

is it possible without explicitly stating the type in ConvertToList? If not, why can T not be inferred in the generic method?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class SomeConverter 
{
    public static List<T> ConvertToList<T>(ArrayLike inputArray)
    {       
        List<T> tList = new List<T>();
        for(int i=0; i < inputArray.Length; i++)            
        {
            tList.Add ((T)(object)inputArray[i]);
        }

        return tList;
    }

}

public class ArrayLike
{
    private string[] arr = new string[100];

    public string this[int i]
    {
        get
        {               
            return arr[i];
        }
        set
        {
            arr[i] = value;
        }
    }

    public int Length { get { return 100; } }
}

class TestClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ArrayLike arrayLike = new ArrayLike();
        arrayLike[0] = "a";
        arrayLike[1] = "b";
        arrayLike[2] = "c";

        List<string> stringList = SomeConverter.ConvertToList(arrayLike);
        foreach(string str in stringList)
            Console.WriteLine (str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is `ConvertToList` generic? It can only take an `ArrayLike`, so the elements have to be strings.

Comment: @Lee well, it also can be parametrized with `object`. But still not much sense

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy - Yes, that's true. It's a shame C# doesn't support lower bounds for generic parameters.

Comment: @Lee explains this lower bounds for generics concept?

Comment: @DavidHaney - In C# you can specify that `T` is a subtype of some given type e.g. `where T : SomeClass`, so `SomeClass` is a lower bound in the type hierarchy for `T`. With upper bounds on generic parameters, you could specify that `T` is a supertype of some class, e.g. `where SomeClass : T` (not legal). Then you could write `ConvertToList` above like `ConvertToList<T>(ArrayLike a) where string : T`. You could then call it with `object` or `IEnumerable<char>` safely. Scala supports upper and lower bounds on generic parameters if you want to find some examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have any generic parameters in this method. So, it can't infer type of T from it's argument. You should specify type generic parameter manually:

```
List<string> stringList = SomeConverter.ConvertToList<string>(arrayLike);
```

Comment: thanks, silly me. Tho it seems that example didn't bring to light the precise issue I'm having. will post to another question.